# Android onactivityresult() not being called in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

This is my code for calling onactivity result. I am using a dialog which prompts to pick image from gallery or from camera. The same code is working in activity but is not working in fragments. I have tried all the previous answers on stackoverflow. Please help

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());

                builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
                builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] { "Pick from Gallery",
                        "Take from Camera" },
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                switch (which) {
                                case 0:

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                                    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                                    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                                    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                                    intent.putExtra("outputX", 250);
                                    intent.putExtra("outputY", 250);

                                    try {

                                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                                        startActivityForResult(
                                                Intent.createChooser(
                                                        intent,
                                                        "Complete action using"),
                                                PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

                                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                                    }

                                    break;

                                case 1:

                                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                                            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                    if (takePictureIntent
                                            .resolveActivity(getActivity()
                                                    .getPackageManager()) != null) {

                                        startActivityForResult(
                                                takePictureIntent,
                                                PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

                                    }

                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                builder.show();





public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
            System.out.print("ho ja please");
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            if (extras2 != null) {
                bitmap = extras2.getParcelable("data");

                Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);


                dp.setImageBitmap(output);


            }
        }

        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 250, 250, true);

            Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

            dp.setImageBitmap(output);



        }
```

Comment: I have tried ur code and its working perfectly to me. Where you have written this code, in fragment only right?

Comment: yes in the fragment only

Comment: I have used ur alertbox in oncreateview and checked. It is working perfectly. You can post the code of fragment

Comment: i have written the code in fragment.. the dialog appears, but when i select a photo from gallery, the image does not set on the imageview.

Comment: Image is not setting is different issue right. U said onactiivtyresult is not called.

Comment: image is setting in onactivityresult and it isnt getting called. I have checked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62653/discussion-between-harsha-vardhan-and-madhav).

Comment: Check your activity and make sure if you have onActivityResult() overridden on your activity, it calls the super.onActivityResult() (this is all in the activity containing the fragment). Just a thought which may or may not fix your problem but I've seen the issue being mentioned before and that was the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by calling startActivityForResult with Activity context i.e.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                                                        intent,
                                                        "Complete action using"),
                                                PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

I am using the below code for showing Image Picker, check this if it helps you -

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1; // Declare this variable

Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
                pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                String pickTitle = "Select or take picture";

                // strings.xml
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent,
                        pickTitle);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });

                getActivity().startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Then in your Activity you can use this -

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if (imageReturnedIntent != null) {
            if (imageReturnedIntent.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData(); // use this URI for getting and updating the fragment


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When u use getActivity().startActivityForResult then onActiivtyResult should be in Activity not in Fragment because the request code in activity comes correct but not in fragment.

Comment: try adding - super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); as your first line of method

Comment: @AshishTamrakar tried this as well. it is not working

Comment: Check the edit, i have added some code there from my application. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

It is because your alert dialog calls Activity.startActivityForResult instead of Fragment.startActivityForResult. If you want to fix that behaviour use the fragment reference inside your dialog to call startActivityForResult.

UPD: also as mentioned [@Ashish Tamrakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3912914/ashish-tamrakar) don't forget to call super.onActivityResult inside your Activity.onActivityResult method if overridden